# When I made an **ajax call** with multiple parameters in the url, the call got blocked. How to send multiple query values with ajax call

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, url, cdn

When I made an **ajax call** with multiple parameters in the url, the call got blocked. How to send multiple query values with ajax call.

```
    $.ajax({
        url:'/order-udate?userId'+UserId,+'/?orderIndex='+orderIndex+'/?productIndex='+productIndex
        method:'get',
        success:(response)=>{
            if(response.status){
                alert("HI")
            }
            else{
                alert("Hu")
            }
        }
    })
```

I think this is not the correct method.

```
url:'/order-udate?userId'+UserId,+'/?orderIndex='+orderIndex+'/?
```

Comment: `the call got blocked` ... what by? ... oh, wait, the syntax is `?param1=value1&param2=value2` not what you got

Comment: The correct (usual) syntax is `'/order-udate?userId='+UserId+'&orderIndex='+orderIndex+'&productIndex='+productIndex`. Check the API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You use `?` to separate the domain from the parameter list, but you use `&` to separate multiple parameters.  And you don't use additional slashes.  Plus, you misspelled "update", and you had the comma in the wrong place.

```
        url:'/order-update?userId'+UserId+'&orderIndex='+orderIndex+'&productIndex='+productIndex,
```

You can let jQuery do this encoding for you:

```
    url: '/order-update',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
        userId: UserId,
        orderIndex: orderIndex,
        productIndex: productIndex
    },
```